# EOFError: Ran out of input pickle.load, file NOT empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Hi I have the following problem:

I have some data, that I have pickled. The data is a dictionary and for each key there is a 3d-numpy array. The data is around 3 GB of size and I can read in the first line showing

```
f = open("data.txt","rb")
print(f.readline())
f.close()

> b'\x80\x03}q\x00(G@\x1a\xe1G\xae\x14z\xe1G@\x1a\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcd\x86q\x01}q\x02(X\x04\x00\x00\x00GABAq\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\n'
```

However if I try to load the pickled data using either

```
f = open("data.txt","rb")
data = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

or

```
f = open("data.txt","rb")
pickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
final   = pickler.load()
```

I only get the error message "EOFError: Ran out of input".

A few additional information: I pickled the data myself using the same PC and Python(3.7.3)/Pickle version

I searched and a few people had this problem and the solution was that their file was empty. I have not found anything helpful.

Thanks in advance

PS:
I pickled the data using:

```
f = open("data.txt","wb")
pickle.dump(data,f) 
f.close()
```

I have used this code quite often with smaller data-sets and never had any problems

Comment: Using `readline()` on a binary file makes no sense and proves nothing even if it "works". The problem may be with how you pickled the data, but your question currently doesn't show this.

Comment: @martineau Using readline() proves that the file is not empty. Regarding how I pickled the data, see edit

Comment: The problem may be because the object is so big. Try using `protocol=4` which adds support for very large objects (see "Protocol version 4" in the [Data stream format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) section of the module's documentation).

Comment: @martineau Yes, I thought about this too. This would require resimulating the data, which is... painfull.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but protocol 4 allows [64-bit pickle "opcodes"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/#bit-opcodes-for-large-objects) — which are necessary for objects over 2 GB. Consider somehow creating a (quick-to-produce) "mock" object and dumping it both ways to verify whether switching to protocol 4 would fix the problem.

Comment: @martineau I think this is not the reason. I just pickled numpy.ones in the same dataformat (therefore also 3,02 GB). I tried it with protocol=4 as additional argument and without. However I could load both without any problem. I fear the textfile,  I cant read in, got somehow corrupted.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's a little strange (and may be dangerous) to give a file containing binary data a `.txt` extension, because that invites changes being made to it to convert line-endings from one convention to another or limit the character codes in it to 7-bit — all of which would corrupt it.